# Why is always first getter with query parameter called in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I have a controller with two functions marked as Get(), both with @Query parameters to receive data. But only the first one in the given order is called even if I send data over that should call the second one. What's wrong with my code?

I already switched positions of both and as explained but always the first function is called.

```
@Controller('pets')
export class PetsController {

  constructor(private readonly petsService: PetsService) {}

  @Get()
  findByCountry(@Query('country') country: string): Promise<Pet> {
    return this.petsService.findByCountry(country);
  }

  @Get()
  findByName(@Query('name') name: string) {
    return this.petsService.findByName(name);
  }
}
```

Normal behaviour should be:

- Call ../api/pets?country=Italy should go into findByCountry(...)
- Call ../api/pets?name=Rudi should go into findByName(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be defining your routes in you `@Get()` decorator with the expected query parameters, otherwise Nest (and Express) will just match the first route. In this case both of your routes look like `'/pets'` with nothing special even though you are attempting to get a query parameter from them. Instead, try setting your controller to look like this

```js
@Controller('pets')
export class PetsController {

  constructor(private readonly petsService: PetsService) {}

  @Get()
  findByCountry(@Query('country') country: string, @Query('name') name: string): Promise<Pet> {
    if (country) {
      return this.petsService.findByCountry(country);
    } else if {
      return this.petService.findByName(name);
    }
  }
}
```

So that you're now running the expected code based on which parameter comes in. Of course this will be a problem if they both come at once.

Comment: Not working. I get a 404 with "Cannot GET /api/pets?name=Rudi".

Comment: Ah, you're right. That does not work. Sorry, I was under the assumption it would. I'll edit my answer.